# flutter: Is it possible to load a list defined by const from another file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have defined a list called quiz in Question.dart.
I need to load this list into main.dart and use it. And I want to use the id value of the quiz in main.dart.
The class in main.dart is StatefulWidget.
How can I solve this?

Question.dart

```
class Question {
  final int id;
  final String options;


  Question({required this.id, required this.options});
}

const List quiz = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "options": 'hello',
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "options": 'good',
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "options": 'abc',
  },
];
```

main.dart

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Body createState() => _Body();
}

class _Body extends State<Body> {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it because it's still declared as `Globally`.quiz defiled outside the Question{} scope.  so you need to just import Question.dart file in main.dart and you can use the quiz list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If so, can you write an example code? I want to store the second id value(2) of the quiz in int a.

Comment: you can just store id in a variable like this: `final id = quiz[2].id ` & for options `final sOptions = quiz[2].options`

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's really simple. It helped a lot.

Comment: When I received the value like this, I got this error.                                                         Class '_ImmutableMap<String, Object>' has no instance getter 'options'.
Receiver: Instance of '_ImmutableMap<String, Object>'
Tried calling: options                                   
Do you know what error it is?

Comment: can you share the error with the image with more details?